# Shader with soft shadows and cel shading

Tags: unity, shaders

I need help understanding what type of shader can create this type of soft shadow:l, where you can barely see that it is low poly:

[image]

With standard lit shader you get this type of shading which I rly don’t like:

[image]

My problem is that I don’t even know what to search for, what is this type of shader called?

Comment: doesn't look toon shaded or cell shaded at all -- just solid art direction. It is using vertex shading instead of face shading like the fox, so you get smooth transitions around the edges of triangles. Not sure about the shadow algorithm but something based on shadow maps.

Comment: @Steven thanks had no idea. When I look up vertex shaders all I find are shaders meant to animate materials (see: https://www.febucci.com/2018/10/vertex-shader/). Is there some link you can provide me or a search I can use to find tutorials or assets for this type of shader?

Comment: I found one old asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vertex-color-trees-set-95968#content. 

Def wont be URP compatible but can give it a look over.

Comment: The main ingredient you're missing is smoothing. You want all the vertex normals for all the triangles meeting at a point to be the same - this will make a smooth shading blend across each edge, instead of a hard crease.

Comment: @dmgregory can I learn how to do that in blender somewhere? Cus I don’t fully understand

Comment: [Yes you can](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+smooth+normals).